# Problems using GlobalMemoryStatusEX on Win32

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fortran, 32bit-64bit

I am facing the following problem: I need to find the available memory on my system. GlobalMemoryStatusEX works fine when built on x64. But gives wrong answer when built on Win32. I am using Intel Visual Fortran 2010 on Windows 7 64-bit.
Here is a sample of my code:

```
program test
use kernel32
use ifwinty
implicit none
type(t_memorystatusex) :: status
integer :: RetVal

status%dwLength = sizeof(status)
RetVal =  GlobalMemoryStatusEX(status)

end program test
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: The wow64 emulator that allows 32-bit code to execute on a 64-bit operating system is pretty powerful, it is very good at convincing 32-bit code that it runs on a 32-bit OS.  Including generating the "wrong" values, a 32-bit OS can never have more than 4 GB of address space of course.  That there actually is more "available memory" is a pointless detail to a 32-bit app, it can't directly take advantage of it.  Use a 64-bit compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program doesn't ever display the values returned, and you don't say what is "wrong", so I don't know what problem you're referring to. Intel Visual Fortran supplies a MemoryStatus example program (in the Win32 sample collection) that uses GlobalMemoryStatusEx. When I run it on my 64-bit system in 32-bit mode it displays:

```
48% of memory is in use
15.99GB total physical memory
8.28GB available physical memory
31.98GB total pageable memory
24.42GB available pageable memory
2.00GB total virtual memory
1.98GB available virtual memory
```

and when run in 64-bit mode:

```
48% of memory is in use
15.99GB total physical memory
8.28GB available physical memory
31.98GB total pageable memory
24.42GB available pageable memory
8192.00GB total virtual memory
8191.99GB available virtual memory
```

Notice that the only difference is in virtual memory, correctly reflecting the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit mode.

In most cases, you don't need to find the amount of available memory - pretty much every indication you can get is not going to be helpful during run of a program. In particular, available virtual memory doesn't necessarily mean you can allocate a single chunk of data that size, as the memory pool may be somewhat fragmented.

So my answer is that your code, what you showed of it, is the correct way to find out what memory, physical and virtual, is available to Windows. You just need to know how to interpret it correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The example from Win32 helped me extract the information I need from GlobalMemoryStatusEX.